# speed issue in my project from pointing to an int

Tags: c++, performance

I am working on a project in which a great number of objects interact with each other. And I am having a performance problem with my code. Lets say it has a structure as described below.

There is a class (lets call it "A") like this:

```
class A
{
   /*Some methods and variables*/

public:
   const int* getPointerToTime() { return &mTime; }

private:
   std::vector<B> mBList;
   int mTime;
}
```

Then there is class "B" like this

```
class B
{
   /*Some methods and variables*/

public:
   B(A* myA) { mTime = myA->getPointerToTime(); }
   int getTime() { return *mTime; }

private:
   std::vector<C> mCList;
   const int* mTime;
}
```

Then there is another class "C" which has a method ("update") that will be called in every cycle of the program. like this:

```
class C
{
   /*Some methods and variables*/

public:
   C(B* myB) { mMyB = myB; }
   void update()
   {
     int t = mMyB->getTime();
     /*some things to do here with "t"*/
   }

private:
   B* mMyB;
}
```

So basically there are a great number of "B" objects in class "A" and there are a great number of "C" in class "B" and in every cycle, each of these objects should be updated. Everything works fine, but I tested its performance using visual studio's performance analysis and interestingly (or maybe not...) the line

```
int t = B->getTime();
```

became the most hot line which got 38% of total samples! And I use this method in other parts of the code. Actually there is somewhere else in the code that I can think of, which is calling this method much more than here but it's sample percentage is not even close to the one used in class "C"! I've suspected maybe the variable in class "A" isn't cached in CPU when the program reaches the update method of "C", but a friend suggested that it is not the case as the speed of computation from L3 and RAM can't make this much difference in speed. So what do you think?

Comment: What optimization settings are you using?

Comment: And what compiler and version are you using, for which operating system & target processor?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch "using visual studio's performance analysis" - now guess the OS...

Comment: Is there any way you can cache the value of time? For example, if you call `int t = B->getTime();` in a loop and the value won't change between iterations, then you can move the line outside of the loop.

Comment: @John Zwinck I tried different optimization options from fully optimizing to minimum and even turn it off but the hot line still remains the same

Comment: @NeilKirk Actually i am doing that, it is not in a loop, it is simply at the beginning of the method and the entire method uses the cached value

Comment: In that case are you sure that line is the one causing the performance bottleneck?

Comment: @NeilKirk That's what performance analysis tool in visual studio is saying...

Comment: Try making `int getTime()` an `inline` function. Just to humour me. Perhaps the bottleneck is the creation of a stack frame.

Comment: @Bathsheba I did it and no difference, but don't worry no one will laugh :D
Also isn't defining a function in class header makes it behave like inline functions?

Comment: Not enough information to say; you could mark the B::getTime() as const, but I don't see this giving the compiler much extra opportunity to optimize. The only other thing is that reading from a cache line that's actively being written to can be quite slower (false sharing basically - impossible to say with what you've shown). Ideally, use someting more capable like VTune to figure those out, the VC profiler just doesn't give you that much information.

Comment: @StefanAtev So I gave Vtune a try wow what a tool! Although I am very impressed with this tool, the report is still the same as VS default profiler

Comment: @sinaTavakoli The point of VTune is that you can enable CPU counters that will let you figure out if there are cache issues, instruction decode issues, weird microarchitecture limitations, stalls, write buffer issues - you already know where your hot spot is, so it doesn't add value there, but it allows you to dig directly at the assembly and to see what events are driving the slow-down; it helps to look at the IPC of individual assembly instructions and gauge what is really happening.

Comment: So _'a great number of "B" objects in class "A" and there are a great number of "C" in class "B" and in every cycle, each of these objects should be updated'_ yet you're surprised that the code invoked by the update function is frequently executed??

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit read the question again and concentrate on the presented facts!

Comment: @sina: I don't need to. I have pointed out a silliness in the question and I stand by it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The silliness is when I mentioned in the question that I have somewhere else in my code that calls the getTime method far more than here and has no problem, and you just traveled all the way from another question to this question to point to something that even a baby can think of! To prove what? Your highness!!

Comment: @sinaTavakoli: Watch your behaviour.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: ok mom!

Answer (score 1):

What I think is, as far as I know Visual Studio

the function B->getTime(); is called more number of times compared to any another function.

Because this function is called by C objects which are members of B class.

With the given code, there is a good chance to that this function is called more times than any another function.

For example 10 Bs have 100 Cs each. Then B->getTime() is called 1000 times in one single loop.

Comment: As I explained, the original code is much more complex than the thing I wrote, there are other objects that exist in "C" and they are calling that method too. but there isn't any problem with them.

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck seems to be in executing the method getTime(), the two de-references shouldn't affect as much as the method execution that is quite expensive in comparison.

Comment: No, that's not the case as I said there are other parts of code in which this method will be called more frequently but those parts didn't become hot.

Comment: It depends what is the most expensive operation made on that thread; maybe caused by the fact that the method is not the most expensive op in that thread?